# Pass Values from TabBarController to child view controllers when selected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I currently have a Tab Bar Controller and two view controller connected to it. However I need to pass values from the TabBarController to the view controller that is selected. So like when a user selects the specific tab, I want to pass a certain value to that view controller. Right now, I have the view controller embedded from the storyboard. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `didSelect`

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
      if let vc = viewController as? SecondVC {
          vc.somePro = <#value#>
      }
}
```

Comment: the tab bar controller is not calling the function though. Do I have to add a delegate method?

Comment: sure you have to set the delegate